# How can I invest a low amount of Moneroj?

Tags: cpu-mining, hashrate

I started mining XMR today with ~500H/s and my power consumption cost is 0. Of course I know 500H/s is a low hashrate to profit. But according to [this page](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/xmr?HashingPower=500&HashingUnit=H%2Fs&PowerConsumption=200&CostPerkWh=0&MiningPoolFee=1) over a year I will have **1.19 XMR**. Let's say I already have that amount.

- Can I use that amount to buy another altcoin? I mean trading or something.
- Can I use it to invest on **Paid To Click** (PTC) sites? I have heard with a low amount of money you can get much more on these sites.

Maybe mining with low hashrate for first world users is silly, but what if you don't have any other way? Of course it will take a lot of time, but can you make even 2000 USD a year with a good investment strategy?

Comment: Beware of "I have heard with a low amount of money you can get much more on this sites". If it's too good to be true, you're usually the mark. Also, 500 H/s is not bad at all.

Comment: Yeah that's the catch, altought I won't be investing too much. On this sites investing more than only a few is dangerous as you suggest. However this world (crytpcurrency trading) really has me curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use that amount to buy another altcoin? I mean trading or something.

Any exchange which accepts Monero also lets you trade Monero for another (crypto)currency. There are dedicated services (e.g. ShapeShift) which allow you to convert coins anonymously.

> Can I use it to invest on Paid To Click (PTC) sites?

I'm not familiar with PTC sites, how would you invest any money into them? I thought they'd pay you and not the other way around.

> Of course it will take a lot of time, but can you make even 2000 USD a year with a good investment strategy?

Sure, just upgrade your mining rig and you can make more than 1 Monero per year :) You can also hodl and wait for the price to moon.

Comment: I guess my question is too broad but this answer almost perfect for newbies like me.